# BottomNavigationView not inflating

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to inflate a BottomNavigationView in `activity_main.xml` but to no avail.

Here's my `bottom_navigation.xml` in the `menu` resource directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="nav_library"
        android:icon="@drawable/svg_library"
        android:title="Library" />

    <item
        android:id="nav_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/svg_search"
        android:title="Search" />

    <item
        android:id="nav_liked"
        android:icon="@drawable/svg_heart"
        android:title="Liked" />

</menu>
```

And here's my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It seems that `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` does not detect the icons nor the title of the menu and as such, the height and width of the navigation bar are both 0.

[Here's an image with the `wrap_content` attribute.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRNT9.png) (Not enough rep for an embed)

Please advise.

P.S This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so my question formatting might not be the best.

Comment: Are there any more views in your activity that may take the space for the BottomNavigationView? Also, do you have the necessary dependency?

Comment: @Ofek No, the only view in the activity screen is BottomNavigationView. For the necessary dependency, I used `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'`. Not sure if that's the right one though.

Comment: I'm not sure if its related or not but you can try to add app:showAsAction="ifRoom" to each of the menu items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late to the party. But I eventually figured it out that day. Was missing the prefix `@+id/`:

```xml
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_library"
        android:icon="@drawable/svg_library"
        android:title="Library" />
```